# Comparación de fechas php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, date, datetime

Estoy haciendo un formulario para un proyecto escolar (soy estudiante de programación). En el formulario se van a registrar "proyectos" y se va a ingresar la fecha de inicio y la fecha de finalización del proyecto, necesito hacer validaciones básicas de estas fechas, como por ejemplo que la fecha de inicio no sea de tal año o que la fecha de finalización no sea más tardía que el año 2030 por ejemplo.

Tengo este código:

```
$FechaI = new DateTime('Y/m/d',($_POST["FechaInicio"]));
$FechaF = new DateTime('Y/m/d',($_POST["FechaFin"]));
$FechaImin = new DateTime('2023/12/12');
if ($FechaI<$FechaImin) {
    echo "<div class='error'>
    La fecha inicial es muy pasada";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    $validarFechaImin=true;
}
```

Ya intenté sin el 'Y/m/d', con 'Y-m-d', con strotime (pero quizá no lo apliqué correctamente), y ya he cambiado el tipo de valor de las fechas del lado de la base de datos, a date, a datetime, a varchar, etc. Pero la validación no se realiza.

Supongo que lo que tengo es un error muy básico, agradecería mucho si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: creo que esto lo tendrías que hacer de manera manual, antes de guardar en la base, no necesitas la base de datos para validar estos campos, a no ser que esas fechas ya estén definidos en una base, para poder realizar dichos cambios, si están así, no es necesario llamarlos como `DataTime()` directamente insértalos así `$_POST["FechaInicio"]` y ahí haces la validación comparando con el valor del `input` del formulario.

Comment: No nos has dicho lo más importante, ¿en qué formato están las fechas? Agrega un `var_dump($_POST);` a tu código y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: [La documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php#example-2042) dice que desde v5.2.2 puedes comparar directamente los objetos DateTime. Para versiones anteriores, puedes comparar directamente las marcas de tiempo [`getTimestamp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) puedes observar que el constructor está esperando como primer parámetro el string con la fecha, no un formato:

```php
// ...
public __construct(string $datetime="now", ?DateTimeZone $timezone=null)
// ...
```

PHP puede instanciar (`new`) un objeto `DateTime` automáticamente con algunos formatos, sin embargo sugiero utilizar `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` para estar siempre seguros.

Si quieres especificar un formato personalizado, entonces usa el método  [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Por ejemplo:

```php
$FechaF = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $_POST["FechaFin"]);
```

Entonces tu código debería quedar así:

```php
<?php

// ### Datos de prueba con formatos distintos
$_POST = ['FechaInicio'=>'2023-07-15', 'FechaFin'=>'2027/12/05'];
// ###

$FechaI = new DateTime($_POST["FechaInicio"]);
$FechaF = new DateTime($_POST["FechaFin"]);
$FechaImin = new DateTime('2023/12/12');
if ($FechaI<$FechaImin) {
    echo "<div class='error'>
    La fecha inicial es muy pasada";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    $validarFechaImin=true;
}
```

Salida: `La fecha inicial es muy pasada`

Answer (score 0):

Estoy haciendo un formulario para un proyecto escolar (soy estudiante de programación). En el formulario se van a registrar "proyectos" y se va a ingresar la fecha de inicio y la fecha de finalización del proyecto, necesito hacer validaciones básicas de estas fechas, como por ejemplo que la fecha de inicio no sea de tal año o que la fecha de finalización no sea más tardía que el año 2030 por ejemplo.

Mi recomendación es que lo trabajes de la siguiente manera:
OPCIÓN 1:

```
$FechaI = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["FechaInicio"]));
$FechaF = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["FechaFin"]));
$FechaImin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2023-12-12'));
if ($FechaI < $FechaImin) {
    echo "<div class='error'>
    La fecha inicial es muy pasada";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    $validarFechaImin=true;
}
```

OPCIÓN 2:

```
$FechaI = strtotime($_POST["FechaInicio"]);
$FechaF = strtotime($_POST["FechaFin"]);
$FechaImin = strtotime('2023-12-12');
if ($FechaI < $FechaImin) {
    echo "<div class='error'>
    La fecha inicial es muy pasada";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    $validarFechaImin=true;
}
```

si deseas extraer el año o el mes de una fecha de las anteriores tres, lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
$anio = date("Y", strtotime($FechaI));
$mes = date("m", strtotime($FechaI));
```